# How to create classes in Boost::Python at run-time?

Tags: python, c++, boost, runtime, boost-python

In module source to create new classes I must use next declarative style constructions:

```
class_<MyClass>("MyClass")
    .def("my_method", &MyClass::my_method)
    .def("my_second_method", &MyClass::my_second_method);
```

But if I need to create classes at run-time? For example module function will be return new class. What I must do?

In fact I need create new types on the fly. In my case this typed fixed dictonairies and typed arrays. I need this for optimize my existing code: overhead problem. In my project used data types that transmitted via network. Its a reason to create fixed dict classes in runtime (every class will store individual fields with specified names, like a structs in C++, it's a `fixed dict` and typed arrays, which the holds element type and array of data of this type).

This will be looks something like this in python code:

```
from MyCPPLib import DeclareFixedDictonary, DeclareTypedArray

# new used defined data type
NewClass = DeclareFixedDictonary([('field_1', int32), ('field_2', String])

# instance of this type
new_instance = NewClass(4, "Hi") 
new_instance['field_1'] = 6
new_instance['field_2'] = "qweqwe"

# ----------------------------------------------
NewArrayClass = DeclareTypedArray(NewClass)
new_array_instance = NewArrayClass([new_instance, NewClass()])

# ----------------------------------------------
NewComplexClass = DeclareFixedDictonary([('f1', float), ('f2', NewArrayClass), (f3, NewClass)])

# ... etc ...
```

I think if I will create this features with C++ using Python::Boost or/and Python API then I will get maximum speed-up with my types.
My problem is creating new classes in runtime (by other function, in example this `DeclareFixedDictonary` and `DeclareTypedArray`).

Following the docs to declare new python class with Boost I must do something like this:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(DataTypes)
{

    class_<DataTypesClass>("DataTypesClass")
        .def("set", &DataTypesClass::set)
        .def("get", &DataTypesClass::get)
        .def("set_item", &DataTypesClass::SetItem)
        .def("get_item", &DataTypesClass::GetItem)
        ;

}
```

But this is *module* classes, they can be created only in my module, and I can't use `class_` in another module function, it's gives error. Maybe Boost has API to create new classes in run-time? Maybe `type` instances and dynamically filling attributes. Or maybe best way to do this is code generation? But is more hard than reflection system in Python.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think this is impossible. You can use inherited python classes from your MyClass or you can generation part your C++ code before compilation instead of making classes at run-time.

Comment: Can you please elaborate and provide an example of what is trying to be accomplished?  All user-defined Python classes created by Boost.Python occurs at runtime.

Comment: @TannerSansbury, I provided an axample and added the details of problem.

Comment: This is technically possible, but it seems like code smell to me.  I suspect that the code will be less than optimal and manageable due to the amount of time execution will cross the language boundary, which can be expensive.  If the application protocol allows for new _data types_ to be introduced on-the-fly, then perhaps the meta-data can be used to create serializer and deserializer objects that convert between the byte protocol and generic-ish Python dict and list-like objects?

Comment: The array side of this looks a lot like numpy record arrays/structured array. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html.